# How to call a Codeigniter function with _remap function from an ajax url?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm working on ajax datatable and when I tried to load the page I got an error

*Datatables warning table id=table - invalid JSON response*

I figured out that it has something to do with the ajax url from datatable seems like it can't locate the controller function that should be loaded.

I'm using a `_remap()`function on my controller that's why I think it's having conflict with urls and my function can't be called.

**This is my controller:**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Requests extends CI_Controller {
var $pgToLoad;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    #this will start the session
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['userId']) || !isset($_SESSION['userLevel']) || !isset($_SESSION['employeeid']) || !isset($_SESSION['firstname']) || !isset($_SESSION['lastname'])) {
        redirect('home', 'location');
    }

    #this will load the model
    $this->load->model('Contents');

    #get last uri segment to determine which content to load
    $continue = true;
    $i = 0;
    do {
        $i++;
        if ($this->uri->segment($i) != "") $this->pgToLoad = $this->uri->segment($i);
        else $continue = false;             
    } while ($continue);        
}

public function index() {   
    $this->load->helper('url'); 
    $this->main();

}   

public function main() {
    #set default content to load 
    $this->pgToLoad = empty($this->pgToLoad) ? "Requests" : $this->pgToLoad;
    $disMsg = "";

    #this will delete the record selected
    if($this->uri->segment(2) == 'leave') { 
        $this->leave();
    }

    #this will logout the user and redirect to the page
    if($this->uri->segment(2) == 'logout') {
        session_destroy();
        redirect('home', 'location');
    }                   

    $data = array ( 'pageTitle' => 'Payroll System | ADMINISTRATION',
                    'disMsg'    => $disMsg,                                             
                    'mainCont'  => $this->mainCont );

    $this->load->view('mainTpl', $data, FALSE);
}



    public function ajax_list()
{
    $list = $this->Contents->get_datatables();
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $leave) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $leave->id;
        $row[] = $leave->type;
        $row[] = $leave->startdate;
        $row[] = $leave->enddate;
        $row[] = $leave->duration;
        $row[] = $leave->reason;
        $row[] = $leave->status;      

        //add html for action
        $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_person('."'".$leave->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_person('."'".$leave->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';

              $data[] = $row;


    }

    $output = array(
                    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                    "recordsTotal" => $this->Contents->count_all(),
                    "recordsFiltered" => $this->Contents->count_filtered(),
                    "data" => $data,
            );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
}

#this will display the form when editing the product
public function leave() {


    $data['employee'] = $this->Contents->exeGetEmpToEdit($_SESSION['userId']);  
        $this->mainCont = $this->load->view('pages/requests/leave', '', TRUE);  

}
 public function _remap () {
    $this->main();
}
```

**Ajax datatable code**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

   //datatables
table = $('#table').DataTable({

    "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
    "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
    "order": [], //Initial no order.

    // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
    "ajax": {
        **"url": "<?php echo site_url('requests/leave')?>",
        "type": "POST"
    },

    //Set column definition initialisation properties.
    "columnDefs": [
    {
        "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
        "orderable": false, //set not orderable
    },
    ],

});
```

What's supposed to be the solution in this case? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case $method == 'IS_AJAX':
```

Your $method is not IS_AJAX with this url:

http://localhost/2fb/index.php/redirect
This would bring you to the redirect controller without a method (will default to "index"). You literally would need:

http://localhost/2fb/index.php/redirect/IS_AJAX
...to step into that case. You seem to be confusing your constant IS_AJAX with the method requested, which you seem to be using correctly when checking for index (although this is the same as the default case, so it's redundant).

$method, or whatever you name the first parameter in _remap(), will always be the routed controller function that is called.

EDIT: I failed to mention this earlier, but the switch block evaluates the expression you pass to it, so there is no need to do the comparison manually. Example:

```
switch ($method) {
    // case $method === 'index':
    case 'index':
        $this->load->view('main');
    break;
}
```